# Usage of InternetGetConnectedStateEx

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to use InternetGetConnectedStateEx but I'm not able to retrieve lpszConnectionName. If I initialise it as 0 I don't get any value, but if I initialised with _T("hol"); I get an access violation

```
    DWORD dwFlags;
    LPTSTR lpszConnectionName = _T("hol");
    DWORD dwNameLen = 3;

    if (InternetGetConnectedStateEx(&dwFlags, lpszConnectionName, dwNameLen, NULL))
    {
        printf("Connected to internet");
    }
    else {
        printf("not connected");
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384705.aspx) says (emphasis mine):

> *lpszConnectionName* **[out]**
>
> Pointer to a string value that **receives** the connection name.

That is an output parameter, that will be filled with the connection name if there is one active. Specifying the contents of this parameter yourself is a mistake, having it point to a string literal doubly so (since modifying it will trigger undefined behavior).

The appropriate way to invoke the function would be something like:

```
DWORD dwFlags;
TCHAR lpszConnectionName[512];

if (InternetGetConnectedStateEx(&dwFlags, lpszConnectionName,
    _countof(lpszConnectionName), NULL)) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. How can I get dwFlags?? I always get 86 and this is not any NTERNET_CONNECTION_####

Comment: @Joan, it's a bit mask. `86` means `64 + 16 + 4 + 2`, or `0x40 + 0x10 + 0x04 + 0x02`, or `INTERNET_CONNECTION_CONFIGURED | 0x10 | INTERNET_CONNECTION_PROXY | INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN`. (The `0x10` flag is apparently undocumented).